# Spawning Nodes randomly between positions

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2, swift3

I'm trying to make a matching game, where these circles appear randomly in a rectangular area, without overlapping. Here's the spawning function:

```
func SpawnRed(){

    var Red = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Matched_Red")
    Red.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
    Red.zPosition = 1

    let MinValueX = self.size.width / 3 + 50
    let MaxValueX = self.size.width / 1.5 - 50
    let MinValueY = self.size.height / 1.5 + 25
    let MaxValueY = self.size.height / 6
    let SpawnPointX = UInt32(MaxValueX - MinValueX)
    let SpawnPointY = UInt32(MaxValueY - MinValueY)

    Red.position = CGPointMake(CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(SpawnPointX)) + MinValueY,CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(SpawnPointY)))

    self.addChild(Red)  
}
```

But for some reason, I keep getting

> "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)" error.

Can you find the solution? Also, it'll be so helpful if you tell me how to spawn nodes without overlapping.

Comment: Go to Breakpoint navigator, add exception break point and see at which line an exception has been raised, and post that line here.

Comment: It just says "All exceptions" on the breakpoint navigator.

Comment: That is okay. Now run the project ...

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Comment: Of course it doesn't work. But you should now see the line where the exception has been raised.

Comment: No line has been raised on any swift file.

Comment: I think you should take a look at this first : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html By the way, your issue is probably related to wrong usage of forced unwrapping ( underlying value of an optional is nil, but you are still unwrapping it in unsafe way) so look if you have something like that in your code. Still, you should learn how to use debugger.

Comment: @Whirlwind or you could just make a better attempt at describing what you're asking him to do in your first comment. What does it do? Where in the Xcode interface is this? Why are you asking for him to do this? Joseph, press [command + 7], this opens the breakpoint navigator. Despite its name, it does more than navigate. There is a plus icon at the bottom left of the navigator, click this and choose Execution Breakpoint. Accept the default values. This will give you information during an error like this, about where it happens in your code, and some other information that's useful.

Comment: Joseph, here's more information on debugging powers in Xcode. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html  Nothing in Xcode is intuitive. It has not been designed, it's simply grown.

Comment: @Confused Sorry, but I don't have time for all that. This should be a trivial task. Put an exception break point like I suggested, then run the app, and the app should stop at the line where the exception is raised. I have noticed that OP is not familiar with terms, so I have pointed him to the docs. Where he should learn basics.

Comment: Everything is at different levels of triviality for different levels of ability, exposure, experience, language skills and terminology knowledge for everyone, all the time.. Some, like me, come at Xcode with expectations of it having been well designed. It isn't, and this provides a constant need to do what would (otherwise) be needless search, discovery and activation of one-time switches... like how to turn on exception flagging. This should be on by default, especially for anyone using Swift.